# Python - Parse a string of lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, converters

http://pastebin.com/tcpmYiMz

In the link above, i have an example of the data i receive when parsing a website, in string form. It is essentially a list of dictionaries, with smaller dictionaries inside.

I would like to be able to parse this data, preferable using JSON. How can i convert this string to a list, and then each dictionary inside that list converted into json?

I've tried using regular list parsing, but i think it gets completely messed up with all the commas inside the dictionaries.

The raw data is not organized this well. It is a long running string with no tabs or spaces.

Thanks!

Comment: I copied that structure in to jsonlint and it is not coming up as a valid json structure. However, you should look in to the json module to perform this work.

Comment: Yea, the data is actually a list of dictionaries. If it were started with [ and ended with ] it would be a list. However, when i try to parse it as a list, it doesn't work, because of the dictionaries inside of the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
import ast
my_obj = ast.literal_eval('[' + d.replace('false', 'False') + ']')

print(type(my_obj))
# prints: <class 'list'>

print(len(my_obj))
# prints: 4
```

Assuming you get the string input as in the link you posted, List parentheses are added because the data structure in there is not valid Python. Then, you will need to make the Python booleans right. You may want to do that for `True` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution, but its messy. If someone has a better way, please tell me, im worried this will break with simple changes to the string.

```
a = '{"skuAttr"'
    b = d.split(a)
    x=0
    for g in b:
        if x != 0:
            if (g[-1] == ","):
                g = g[:-1]

            print json.loads(('{"skuAttr"' + g))
        x+=1
```

Basically, its just splitting the string by what i found to be the very first characters, then adding them back in at the end, removing the commas if are there, and then loading each dictionary separately. Inefficient and not change resistant, but it works right now